# Resizing with snap in interact.js

Tags: javascript, interact.js

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/2te6fbak/1/) I have an interact.js rect that can be resized with a snap of 10px by 10px. The rect is positioned in x = 95px, and when I move the left side to the left, it moves to x = 90x. This is fine, however the right side also moves to the right and it shouldn't.

What's wrong with this code? The rect has handles, is that creating the problem?

```
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {

    const target = event.target.querySelector('rect');

    for (const attr of ['width', 'height']) {
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(attr));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(attr, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    for (const attr of ['top', 'left']) {
      const a = attr == 'left' ? 'x' : 'y';
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(a));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(a, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    findLocations(rect, handles);


 });
```

Comment: Are you saying that you **don't** want the side that wasn't interacted with to snap to the grid?

Comment: exactly, if you don't move that side explicitly, it should not move

Comment: Will this rectangle ever be *moved*, or just *resized*?

Comment: In this example, only resized (in the real case it is also dragged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I see the problem. Here's what's happening: when the rectangle is resized, you're rounding both the size and the position. This has the following effect that:

- You have a rect whose sides go from `x = 95` to `x = 115`. It has its left side moved by `-3` units. It is now `92` to `115`.
- You check the width: it is `115 - 92 = 23` units across, so you round to the nearest ten: `20` units.
- You check the position: It is on `92`, so you move it to `90`. **This slides the entire, now resized, rectangle over.**

You'll need to handle the `top` and `left` cases differently from the `right` and `bottom` cases, since the former two update the rectangles position on top of its size. On top of that, you'll have to only round the respective side that was changed: you don't want to round the bottom when you move the right.

- For `left` or `top`...

  - Move the `x` or `y` to the new position, rounded
  - *Don't* round `width` or `height`, since that will move `right` or `bottom`
- For `right` or `bottom`...

  - Do nothing to `x` or `y`, since rounding them will budge the whole rectangle over
  - Well, we can still change `x` or `y`, since they'll be zero, but we can't round them!
  - *Only* change the `width` or `hight`, but round this time

That's quite a few cases to check for, but by using a function, this isn't too hard to see how it all works:

```js
.on('resizemove', function(event) {
  const target = event.target.querySelector('rect');

  function changeVal(attr, change, round) {
    let val = Number(target.getAttribute(change));
    val += event.deltaRect[attr];
    if (round) val = Math.round(val / 10) * 10;
    target.setAttribute(change, val);
  }

  let round = false;
  if (event.deltaRect.top != 0) round = true;
  changeVal('top', 'y', round);

  round = false;
  if (event.deltaRect.left != 0) round = true;
  changeVal('left', 'x', round);

  round = false;
  if (event.deltaRect.right != 0) round = true;
  changeVal('width', 'width', round);

  round = false;
  if (event.deltaRect.bottom != 0) round = true;
  changeVal('height', 'height', round);

  findLocations(rect, handles);
});
```

Shortening this and changing to the same loop style as before:

```js
.on('resizemove', function(event) {
  const target = event.target.querySelector('rect');

  const attributes = [
    { check: 'top', change: 'y' },
    { check: 'left', change: 'x' },
    { check: 'right', change: 'width' },
    { check: 'bottom', change: 'height' }
  ];

  for (const {check, change} of attributes) {
    let val = Number(target.getAttribute(change));
    val += event.deltaRect[check];
    if (event.deltaRect[check]) val = Math.round(val / 10) * 10;
    target.setAttribute(change, val);
  }

  findLocations(rect, handles);
});
```

This uses [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so it won't work in IE.

---

There still seems to be some jankiness on the right edge when resizing the left edge, but I think that's an error with rounding...?

Even if not, I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Yes, the right moves probably because of the rounding, I think rounding will not work, I was trying to find a solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973085/making-interact-js-resizable-pixel-perfect)

Comment: @ps0604 The last thing I would try if you haven't already is to set a breakpoint inside the `'resizemove'` event handler and watch what happens when it resizes: see if you can catch why the right edge is moving?